# SlSvcUtil.exe The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TSL secure channel

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, cmd, xamarin

I have a WCF service on a development server (IIS). The service has a self signed SSL and username authentication enabled on it.

I've setup a test ASP MVC project that can successfully call data from the service like so:

```
        CategoryServiceClient csc = new CategoryServiceClient();
        csc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
        csc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

        var a = csc.GetCategories();
```

While I'm using a self signed certificate the call to `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` works in this instance.

The problem is that I want to use this service for a Xamarin project which requires me to use the SlSvcUtil.exe to build the client side code.

In the command prompt I navigate to the SLSvcUtil directory:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Tools
```

Then I run this cmd to generate the code docs:

```
SlSvcUtil.exe https://x.x.x.x:2022/CategoryService.svc /directory:"c:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\Services"
```

This fails with the following error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TSL secure channel.
```

How can I run this command without the validation check or automatically pass the validation like my code sample?

-or-

How can I use Xamarin to generate a service reference for a WCF service that is using SSL?

-or-

How can I make my self signed (development) SSL cert be able to establish a trust relationship?

Comment: Try adding a web reference directly from xamarin Studio

Comment: Adding a web reference directly from Xamarin produces another error I have queried here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936247/xamarin-how-to-add-service-reference-to-ssl-username-authentication-wcf-service it appears Xamarin doesn't like self signed certs or SSL

Comment: I am facing the similar issue.any one got the solution for this scenarion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Xamarin doesn't work very well with SSL or the type of reference you would use with WCF.

In the end we trashed the WCF component and went with the ASP Web API.

JSON back and forth, a little more leg work was needed but it's soo much easier to use/debug and happens to be more cross compatible also.